# Remove Border from the last li Element of an Unordered List

Tags: php

I have an **ul list** with a query and a while loop displaying the **li's** inside.

Each li has a border bottom. I need to find a way to make the last li not have a border.

Here is what I am thinking:

```
<ul> 

$z = '0'; 

$anchors2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM anchors WHERE site_url = '$site_current2'  AND site_type = 'slave' LIMIT 999 OFFSET 9"); 

while($anc2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($anchors2)){

    $z++;

    $s_anchor2 = $anc2['site_anchor']; 

    $s_current2 = $anc2['site_current'];

    if ($z != $total_number_of_rows){ // How can I get the total number of queried rows?

        echo '<li><a href="'.$s_current2.'" title="'.$s_anchor2.'" target="_self">'.$s_anchor2.'</a></li>';             

   } else {

        echo '<li style="border-bottom:none"><a href="'.$s_current2.'" title="'.$s_anchor2.'" target="_self">'.$s_anchor2.'</a></li>';  
                    }                   
   }

</ul>
```

****The problem is I need a way to find out the total number of rows in order to make my code work and remove the border of the last li**

Any ideas?

Just tried it with jquery which I new to me. I have several ul lists and here is the code:

```
function last_li_remove_border() {
    $("ul.no_border_last_li li:last").each(function() {
        css({border:'none'});
    });
}
```

How can i make it work?

Ty for the answers:)

Comment: Number of rows queried: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 ways:

1. Use `mysql_num_rows($anchors2)` to find out how many rows there are.
2. Use the CSS last-of-type selector
3. Use jQuery or some other JS library. jQuery would look like:

   `$("li:last").css({border-bottom:'none'});`

I'd choose 2, as it means that html is consistent - you shouldn't be using inline CSS if possible. If not 2, then 1. Using jQuery would be my last resort, by a huge massive margin!

Comment: Hello, ty very much, I like the Jquery idea, tried a code in my answer, can you please take a look? I have several ul which need their borders removed. If i apply the code you gave me directly it seems to only work on the last ul

Comment: Using jQuery isn't a good way to do this - use mysql_num_rows to find out how many rows instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use jquery for that? using li:last you should be easily able to do it!

Comment: I am a newb with jquery, would be awesome, can you give me an example? Pls

Comment: I guess you have the answer you needed with following comments ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use [JQuery](http://jquery.com):

$("li:last").css({border:'none'});

**A quick crash course**

> ```
> $("li:last") explained
> $() is the JQuery call
> li:last (simple CSS selector)
> .css({border:'none'}) add a CSS parameter border:none
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Why use inline coding or jquery? This is easily done in css, and this belongs logically in at the style-level. This is what the :last-child pseudo-class is for: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html

Comment: Its not cross-browser compatible, some old browsers ignore it

Comment: True (damn you ie), but there are htc and js fixes for this (see http://dean.edwards.name/IE7/) that make IE much more css2/3 compliant, and which will allow you to leave you code as it "should be" :)

Comment: JQuery = JS fix ;) Actually JQuery = Awesome and should be more widely used

Comment: I don't challenge that jQuery is awesome, but it is too specific a fix. If possible, css should be doing this type of work. Edwards' library serves as a generic patch for IE's poor css application, allowing you to write code "as if" the browser was using only css. This makes the code more recyclable for future projects (now that ie does support this) and it will be lighter for non-ie browsers as you can make it a conditional library (<!--[if lte IE 8]><![endif]-->). I'm not trying to be a zealot about it, but it is conceptually more straight-forward not to have to write a jquery fix.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jeremy. Use jQuery to handle that with a simple `$('li:last').css({'border-bottom':'none'});`

But to answer your question, you can get the number of rows with `mysql_num_rows();`
`$total_number_of_rows=mysql_num_rows($anchors2);` Would work in your example

Dont forget to increment $z just before the end of the loop -  `$z++`

-ignore that, just saw youare $z++ ing :) going to go make more coffee now :D

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:last-child` pseudo-class in CSS. Assuming your `<ul>` has the class "list", the CSS would be

```
ul.list li { border-bottom: 1px solid black; }
ul.list li:last-child { border-bottom: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you were asking how to get the number of rows, if thats true you can try: `mysqli_num_rows`